# How can I open installed apps same "firefox" on remote computers?

Tags: c#, network-programming, wmi, remote-access

I want to connect remotely to another computer in network and run its applications remotely.
I use WMI for connecting to network PCs , when I try to run application like "firefox" on it by creating wmi_process, it creates firefox.exe in process task manager, but it doesn't run it!( firefox.exe is run in background and is not opened!)

I want to open apps too. Can I do that? 
Is any other way to remote connecting and running programs that installed on computer?
thanks...

```
 public void RunApps(string AppName)
 {
      ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
      ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Product");

      string loc = string.Empty;
      foreach (ManagementObject mo in managementObjectCollection)
      {
          if (mo["name"].ToString() == AppName)
          {
              loc = mo["InstallLocation"].ToString();
          }
      }

      loc += AppName + ".exe";

      ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process");
      ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
      inParams["CommandLine"] = loc;// "calc.exe";
      ManagementBaseObject outParams =processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this isn't possible using WMI. You can't create *interactive* remote processes in this way for security reasons.

See Microsoft documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> You can use Win32_Process.Create to execute a script or application on
>   a remote computer. However, for security reasons, the process **cannot
>   be interactive**. When Win32_Process.Create is called on the local
>   computer, the process can be interactive.

This is exactly what your code above is trying to do - so you can create a process, but it will not be able to *interact* with the user (it cannot create a visible window, for example).